# Increasing sequence of dice rolls, explanation of "6 choose 2"

Tags: probability, dice

With a 6 sided die, what is the probability of 3 rolls being increasing?

I understand from reading other questions that the answer is $\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{6^3}$. The $6^3$ on the denominator makes sense. Can someone please explain to me why it's choose 2, and what that part means?

Comment: The answer should be $\dfrac{\binom{6}{3}}{6^3}$, because there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose three numbers from $6$.

Answer (score 4):

There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ distinct numbers. Any such choice can be arranged in order in only one way.

Thus the numerator should be $\binom{6}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom63=20$ sets of $3$ distinct numbers chosen from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and each of those can be arranged in increasing order in exactly one way, so there are $\binom63$ **strictly** increasing sequences of $3$ die rolls. The probability of getting one of them is therefore $\dfrac{20}{6^3}=\dfrac5{54}$, not $\dfrac{\binom62}{6^3}=\dfrac{15}{216}=\dfrac5{72}$.

If you allow all non-decreasing sequences, there are in addition $6$ constant sequences, and such sequences as $\langle 1,3,3\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1,3\rangle$ containing two distinct entries. There are $\binom62$ ways to choose which $2$ numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ are represented, and then there $2$ ways to choose which one appears twice, so there are $2\binom62$ sequences of this type. Thus, the number of non-decreasing sequences is

$$\binom63+6+2\binom62=20+6+30=56\;,$$

and the probability of getting one of them is $\dfrac{56}{216}=\dfrac7{27}$.

Comment: I failed to mention that it does not include constants. my apologies. Can you explain, just generally, what the concept of 6 choose 3 means? I don't really understand it.

Comment: @Nick: $\binom{n}k$ can be defined as the number of different $k$-element subsets of a set of $n$ distinct elements. For instance, $\binom42=6$, and the $6$ two-element subsets of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ are $\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{0,3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\}$, and $\{2,3\}$. If one defines $\binom{n}k$ in that way, one then proves that $$\binom{n}k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\;,$$ provided that $0\le k\le n$.